# Turn columns into values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data:

```
     date_ country category_A category_B
2022-12-11     USA        100        200
2022-12-11  Canada       2000        400
```

which is generated by this query:

```
select
  date('2022-12-11') as date_, 'USA' as country, 100 as category_A, 200 as category_B,
union all select 
  date('2022-12-11') as date_, 'Canada' as country, 2000 as category_A, 400 as category_B
```

What I would like to do is to turn only the last two columns of the data into values and get a single column for the values, like this table:

```
     date_ country   category  value 
2022-12-11     USA category_A    100       
2022-12-11     USA category_B    200        
2022-12-11  Canada category_A   2000   
2022-12-11  Canada category_B    400
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not perfect but you can use the following query :

```sql
with countries AS
(select
  date('2022-12-11') as date_, 'USA' as country, 100 as category_A, 200 as category_B,
union all select 
  date('2022-12-11') as date_, 'Canada' as country, 2000 as category_A, 400 as category_B
)

select 
  date_,
  country,
  category
from countries,
unnest(array[struct('category_A' AS category_name, category_A AS category_value), struct('category_B' AS category_name, category_B AS category_value)]) as category;
```

The result is :

[image]

In the `unnest`, you need to add all the expected category columns.